# Changing input value inside a form tags when ENTER key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

Consider the following HTML code:

```
<form>
    <div>
        <input type ="text" id="myInput"/>
    </div>
</form>
```

I would like that when the user write some text and press the ENTER key, the input value will change to the word "Hello".

To do so I add the following Java Script code:

```
<script>
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      input.value ="Hello";
    }
});
</script>
```

Unfortunately, that didn't work as when I write a text and press the ENTER key, the text disappeared (instead of showing the world "Hello").

After digging a little into the problem I figured out that if I would remove the "form" tags from the HTML code, then it would work fine.

I have two questions:

1) Why this is happening?

2) How to solve this problem without removing the "form" tags?

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: "How to solve this problem without removing the "form" tags?" — Why? You don't want a new page to load, so why do you want the form in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. This is happening because "Enter" attempts to submit the form.
2. Migrating your code to onSubmit event handler can fix the issue without removing the form tag.

I've attached the snippet. Let me know if this what you're expecting.

```html
<form onSubmit="changeToHello(event)">
    <div>
        <input type ="text" id="myInput"/>
    </div>
</form>
<script>
function changeToHello(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  input.value ="Hello";
}
</script>
```

Comment: Hi Avanthika, this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!!

Comment: As there's no actual submitting of the form intended, I would suggest also adding a `return false;` statement so it doesn't reload the page, e.g.
`<form onSubmit="changeToHello(event); return false;">`

Answer (score 0):

`preventDefault()` prevents the default behaviour of the event.

There is no default behaviour of a keyup event to prevent here, so it has no effect.

The keypress event runs too, and its default behaviour when you press enter is to submit the form.

Answer (score -1):

The Form function in HTML looks to submit the data entered. Usually you would add an 'action' which just submits your form to a server (i.e. action="action.php"). Because there is no "action" you are essentially just refreshing the page. To get around this you would need to use AJAX and it's preventDefault() function to stop the form from submitting (refreshing the page).

Comment: "To get around this you would need to use AJAX" — The OP said nothing about making an HTTP request. Only changing the value to Hello.

Comment: "it's preventDefault() function" — `preventDefault` is a method on event objects, it has nothing to do with Ajax. The OP is already using `preventDefault` in the code in the question.

Comment: "A form is essentially a container that can be used to hold any amount of any subset of several types of data. HTML forms are used to pass data to a server." -Stackoverflow

Comment: "I would like that when the user write some text and press the ENTER key, the input value will change to the word "Hello"." — This question.

Comment: The nature of a Form is to submit these requests, that is why the AJAX is needed.

Comment: The nature of a Form is to submit these requests … which is why it is reasonable to question why the OP wants to keep the form. Their goals don't seem to involve submitting any data to the server.